# Inline jQuery/AJAX not working in Expression Engine

Tags: jquery, ajax, expressionengine

I have some inline jQuery to load Disqus comments on demand for my Expression Engine template, but for some strange reason I'm having a problem getting this to work properly:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('.show-comments').on('click', function(){
                var disqus_shortname = 'xxxxxxx'; // Replace this value with *your* username.
                var disqus_identifier = 'xxxxxxxxxxx_{exp:channel:entries disable='categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination' channel='channel'}{entry_id}{/exp:channel:entries}';
                var disqus_url = '{site_url}xxxxxx/xxxxx/{exp:channel:entries disable='categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination' channel='channel'}{url_title}{/exp:channel:entries}';

                // ajax request to load the disqus javascript
                jQuery.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://" + disqus_shortname + ".disqus.com/embed.js",
                dataType: "script",
                cache: true
                });
                // hide the button once comments load
                jQuery(this).fadeOut();
                });
                });
```

It works fine when called from an external JS file, but fails when inside the html file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: In what way does it fail? What errors are occurring? (i'm expecting `jQuery is not defined`

Comment: Hi Kevin. Well, the "load disqus comments" button is supposed to load the script and display the Disqus comments. I want people to be able to load Disqus on demand instead of having it load automatically.

Comment: When you say inline, where is this JS embedded? Remember to embed it after jQuery has been loaded. Also, are there any error messages on your browser's console?

Comment: Hi Terry. The JS is embedded under within an <article> tag set underneath the Disqud thread div. I have jQuery loading in the footer. Should it be placed in the header instead?

Comment: @user2485157 I get that it doesn't do what you think it should. But that doesn't help us help you solve it. there has to be a reason it isn't doing what you think it should. I don't see anything in your code that would make it behave weirdly based on how/where you include it in the page.

Comment: I think the main problem was that jQuery wasn't loading first. It seems to be working fine now. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jQuery needs to be loaded BEFORE running any scripts that call jQuery functions. So either move this script to the footer (below the script that loads jQuery), or move the jQuery load to the head of your page.